# Pulling data from another workbook using VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of unique project IDs in 2 workbooks.  One of the workbooks doesn't contain the details of the projects, while the other workbook contains all of the project details.

I want to pull out the information from one workbook according to the unique project ID found in the other workbook. I have tried coding this, but it only works for extracting the data from the external workbook for the one with the project ID.  I need it to work to extract the data for a range of project IDs given in a column.

This is the code I currently have:

```
Sub AAA()

    If Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value Then
        Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

This code only works for a particular cell, but I would need to extract a range of data from a range of project IDs located in the external workbook.  What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: This sounds like the type of request for which the built-in `VLOOKUP` function works. Have you considered using this non-VBA approach? If so, can you tell us why it didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your question you need to add one more loop try this

```
Sub copydata()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim targetlastrow As Long, sourcelstrow As Long
Dim Sourcelastcol As Long
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet

Set source = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")
Set target = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

targetlastrow = target.Range("A" & target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sourcelstrow = source.Range("A" & source.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sourcelastcol = source.Cells(2, source.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To targetlastrow
    For j = 2 To sourcelstrow
        If target.Range("A" & i).Value = source.Range("A" & j) Then
            source.Activate
            source.Range("B" & j).Select
            Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, Sourcelastcol)).Copy
            target.Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Not copy the entire row but based on their project ID. So if in source workbook contain that project ID, the details will be copied to the target workbook based on the same project IDs. I have tried your coding but it seems to only read ine project ID and copied it to the whole range which is not what i was looking for. I hope you could assist me

Comment: HI! it seems you are trying to copy only particular columns in source book and paste them into target. if that is right please provide which column has to copy from source and in which column it has to be pasted in target. or you can change the code for your convenient

Comment: However I would also need the code to run through each row to match the other Project IDs found in the other workbook. The codes above only works if both Project IDs as in the same row. Is there a code that I could use to look through all the rows of column that contain the Project IDs from both the Workbooks? @Nitish

Comment: Hi! for that you need to add one more loop I have updated the above answer check that

Comment: Hi i already used the code that you have updated. it works! thank you! However i have one more problem, i realize that my columns for both workbook is not the same. For example header column C in "Target" workbook is found in header column D in "Source" workbook. Thus if i were to do the code you gave, it will copy and paste the information in the wrong column. Is there any idea that i could use to copy it correctly? @Nitish

Comment: Hi may i know the 0 found on "Range.(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0,Sourcelastcol)).Copy" is used for? @Nitish

Comment: ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=3)